# Why laravel build didnt works?

Tags: linux, laravel, docker, curl, wsl-2

I installed docker and set wsl 2  but idk why "laravel.build"
isn't work's when i press enter i got empty result in command line.

[See screenshoot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GROEx.png)

Comment: If you just do `curl -s "https://laravel.build/tal"`, do you see the install script?

Comment: no nothing no loading progress or anything else

Comment: Then curl isn't working. If you can't fix that, then you could go to `https://laravel.build/tal` in a browser, save the script and run it manually.

Comment: too much loading

Comment: OK. I guess I'll just wish you the best of luck then :)